# Calling a JavaScript function when a button is clicked in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function

I am creating a calculator using ASP.NET and JavaScript.  When the user clicks the button, right now trying to get it to work for button 7, it calls a javascript function in order to see if the user clicked the clear button, the back space button, or if they clicked a number button.  If it is a number button, the function is suppose to add the number to the textbox.  For example, if the user clicks 7 then clicks 8, then clicks *, and then clicks 1, the text box will display: 78*1.  I can't get the javascript function to work.  I am currently just trying to get it so when button 7 is clicked, it adds the 7 to the text box.  Below is my code:

```
   <script>
   var maxInputLength = 20;

  function checkButtonClick(clickedValue)
  {
      var buttonValue = clickedValue.value;
      var inputStr = document.getElementById('inputBox').value;

      if (buttonValue == 'C')
      {
          document.getElementById('inputBox').value = "";
      }
      else
      {
          if (inputStr.length < maxLength)
          {
              var num = 6;
              document.getElementById('inputBox').value = inputStr + buttonValue + num;
          }
          else
          {
              //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Maxmum length is " + maxInputLength;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  document.getElementById('inputBox').readOnly = true;
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <div id="main" class="main">
          <div id="content" class="content">
            <h3 id="h3">Simple Calculator</h3>
                <div id="calculatorDiv">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                           <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="inputBox" disabled="disabled" ID="inputBox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonNum7" runat="server" Text="7" CssClass="CalcButtons" OnClientClick="return checkButtonClick(7)" />
                        </td>
```

Comment: if you are calling `checkButtonClick(7)` then why are you doing `clickedValue.value` ? Just take the `clickedValue`

Comment: Also - you can make it generic for all buttons: `checkButtonClick($(this).attr('Text'))` and attach `checkButtonClick` for all buttons.

Comment: I was calling my maxInputLength by using mexLength so it was never running that part of the function.  TY Omri for pointing that out.  I tried using your way of making it generic for all buttons but isnt that PHP syntax?

Comment: That's jquery. You're right, you tagged javascript but I wrote jQuery code. Take a look at my answer, I updated it and the fiddler demo to use javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I started writing many comments I figured I'll just sum this up in an answer.

Several things in your code didn't wire up for me. You had `maxLength` which is undefined.
Also, you should take the value straight from the function and not with the `.Value`, like this:

```
function checkButtonClick(clickedValue)
{
      var buttonValue = clickedValue;
      // rest of code
}
```

Please see [Fiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UC5Nf/1/) for a demonstration.